# Unity 2d Ragdoll Inconsistent issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, unityscript, ragdoll

I have a 2d character(side scrolling) with run/idle animations and movement works fine too. also character is attached with die/ragdoll script and this script does 
1- disable animator
2- disable rigidbody(for whole character)
3- disable collider(box collider for whole body)
4- disable script
and to enable ragdoll
5 - enable collider for each body parts (body,head,legs,arms..etc)
6 - enable hinge joints for each body  parts with limited angles
7 - enable rigid bodies for each body parts
Now the problem is when this script is called, inconsistently the whole body falls down with a jerk of 2 - 3 inches.
am i missing anything when i need to do ragdoll, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Now i added one more step and its fine now.
8 - by default set the gravity scale (of rigid body parts)to 0 and when character dies set it back to needed value.